# android back key still not working in my game in cocos2d-x android c++

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I have used

```
virtual void keyBackClicked();
```

in my helloworld.h and provided the definition in my .cpp

```
void HelloWorld:: keyBackClicked()
{
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->end();
}
```

My helloworld class in also inheriting cclayer class.
I am using cocos2dx 2.2
But still its not working for android.Nothing is happening on pressing back key.How can I resolve this issue..tried many times.I have seen many posts and everywhere it is written the same logic.
Can anyone please help.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable keyboard using `setKeypadEnabled(true);` method in your Layer `init()` or `onEnter()` method.